# CacheItemRemovedCallback in ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc

I did a first pass google search looking for the equivalent method of CacheItemRemovedCallback in asp.net Core and so far have come up empty.  I use cache invalidation to act as a pseudo service / timer in some of the web apps I'm looking to more to Core.

Any direction you wise internet gods could toss my way on this is appreciated.

Update: I created an OWIN class that seems to be called correctly on startup, but the cache invalidation never gets called.  I'm miss'en som'en.

```
public class OwinCacheTimer
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    private IMemoryCache cache;

    public OwinCacheTimer(RequestDelegate next, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        this.cache = memoryCache;
        this.next = next;
        SetCache(this);
    }

    public  void SetCache(object o)
    {
        /* do work */

        MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        options.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(21);
        options.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        options.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(ExpiredCallback, o);  // <- this doesn't fire
        IMemoryCache x = ((OwinCacheTimer)o).cache;

        /* setting whateve, just so something expires */
        x.Set<string>("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString(), options);
    }


    public void ExpiredCallback(object key, object value, EvictionReason reason, object state)
    {
         SetCache(state);

    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(context);
        await this.next.Invoke(context);
        this.EndInvoke(context);
    }

    private void BeginInvoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Do custom work before controller execution
    }

    private void EndInvoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Do custom work after controller execution
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this article seems to discuss a similar concept, but it looks like caching is bound to a controller, which might change up being able to use cache invalidation as kind of a permanent service/timer thing.  I will play with it and see. http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/a7d9edfd-1f86-45f8-a668-64cc86d8e248.aspx

Comment: I also could be way off here, the caching example above is for a controller, I tried to hack that into an OWIN class, maybe that isn't doable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I'm going about this all wrong.  You can now schedule task and don't have to do the above type hacks, though if it is possible I'd still like to know how to do it the above way. It looks like the correct what to schedule task is along these lines, just FYI-

https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html

Comment: Any information about options.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(ExpiredCallback, o); not firing ? I need to call some function on cache expiration time of every object stored in cache, Example save the data stored on the cache, Any Idea? . This was possible with System.Web.Caching library

Comment: To be honest I punted this and never got back to it.  At the time the only documentation for this that I found was the above link.  I think I fooled around with System.Web.Caching but didn't get anywhere before punting.